# Is there a Ubuntu version of mega [mega.co.nz] client?

Tags: software-recommendation

The new Mega provides much more free space than Dropbox or other competitors and last but not least privacy finally arrived to the world of cloud storages. If there is no client then is it possible to use some synchronization software to sync my folders with mega?

Comment: All in not well in **Mega.co[m]**-land: http://www.nbr.co.nz/mega - *"LIVE BLOG: Mega launch - service falls over as 250,000 join in first two hours"*

Comment: well... now it's a closed post but actually they released a client. It's compatible with debian and fedora based distros. More info and how to install it here: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/09/install-mega-client-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: For the people still searching, I have a Q/A on [how to install the Mega Sync Client](http://askubuntu.com/q/545299/36315), here on Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there is no client or local sync method. At the moment all you can use is their website and upload method.

They do have a developer section on their site: [MEGA - Developers - MEGA Software Development Kit](https://mega.co.nz/#developers) Give it a bit of time since this website is less than 1 day old and it should be possible to create something like U1/dropbox for this site.

Comment: As of 2013-03-08  there is a command-line tool set for Ubuntu called [`megatools`](http://megatools.megous.com/). However, [the PPA](https://launchpad.net/~megous/+archive/ppa) doesn't have a `raring` version. There's a [Github issue](https://github.com/megous/megatools/issues/29) about it. I'll try to create a new PPA sometime soon.

Comment: @RobinWinslow cool! create an answer or edit mine when you are done! Or PM me and I'll edit it in :)

Comment: I can't create an answer 'cos the question is closed. I'll edit yours when I have a reliable PPA to link to.

Comment: The developer has stopped developing megatools [due to the annoying restrictions](http://megatools.megous.com/) of the new Mega API licence.