# How can I integrate Mega into Ubuntu?

Tags: application-development, backup, file-sharing, client, upload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a Ubuntu version of mega [mega.co.nz] client?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/245118/is-there-a-ubuntu-version-of-mega-mega-co-nz-client)

Any plugins I can use that might help until Mega makes a client for Ubuntu?

I'm running 12.04 so the desktop-webapp option isn't there, and besides that wouldn't be the same.