# How do I install the Mega Sync Client

Tags: backup, cloud, mega

How do I install the Dropbox alternative: [Mega Sync Client?](https://mega.co.nz/#sync)

Comment: There's a good article about this on [webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/09/download-megasync-for-linux-desktops.html)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For the people that don't know, [MEGA](https://www.mega.co.nz/) is a Dropbox alternative, with 50GB of free storage, available for Mac, Windows and Linux, created by [Kim Dotcom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kim_Dotcom).

I have been using Mega for months now, and it has turned into my new default Cloud Storage Service.

Although some features are not present, such as, file previewer for Document files(`.doc`/`.pdf`/`.txt`). Image previewer works just fine.

### Features

Here are some features that are [touted](https://mega.co.nz/#sync) by Mega:

- Secure:

  - Your data is encrypted end to end. Nobody can intercept it while in storage or in transit.
- Flexible:

  - Sync any folder from your PC to any folder in the cloud. Sync any number of folders in parallel.
- Fast:

  - Take advantage of MEGA's high-powered infrastructure and multi-connection transfers.
- Generous:

  - Store up to 50 GB for free!

> All encryption is end-to-end. Data uploaded is encrypted on the
>   uploading device before it is sent out to the Internet, and data
>   downloaded is decrypted only after it has arrived on the downloading
>   device. The client machines are responsible for generating, exchanging
>   and managing the encryption keys. No usable encryption keys ever leave
>   the client computers (with the exception of RSA public keys). - [MEGA](https://mega.co.nz/)
>   from [MEGA - Help - Security](https://mega.co.nz/#help/security)

### Installation

Download the [Mega Sync Client](https://mega.co.nz/#sync) for Linux. Open the terminal in the directory you downloaded the deb file, then Copy/Paste the following code: `sudo dpkg -i megasync-xUbuntu_14.04_amd64.deb`. After that start mega from the Dash, from there one it will start up at login.

**Note**:

The deb file also adds a [ppa](https://mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/xUbuntu_14.04/) in your sources list. Meaning future updates, you will get via your Software Updater.

For the people that don't trust any type of PPA, but still want mega, I uploaded the binary: [`megasync-gui`](https://www.virustotal.com/nl/file/77ab9444211d747fd926504b412880058eacbe9ad22030aa75a8cc889a3d091d/analysis/1415038519/) to [virustotal](https://www.virustotal.com/).

Mega sync will start automatically: In the unity panel you will see a MEGA icon which gives you multiple options to choose from.

### Screenshots

[image: Mega Sync Client - Linux]

[image: Mega Sync Client - settings - Synchronizations]

[image: Mega Sync Client - settings - Bandwidth]

[image: Mega Sync Client - settings - proxy]

[image: Mega Sync Client - settings - advanced]

For any help with Mega, see there [Mega Sync Client help page](https://mega.co.nz/#help).

**Source**:

Excerpt from:

- [Mega Sync Client For Linux - EuroBytes](http://www.eurobytes.nl/tutorials/mega-sync-client-for-linux)

which I am the author of.

Comment: My Personal Package Archive is outdated because I couldn't get the current MEGASync sources anymore. Sorry :-( Otto PS: You can obtain the binary packages from here: https://mega.co.nz/linux/MEGAsync/

Comment: @user2867516, it seems that when installing the megasync via deb, it also adds, it's ppa. See me updated answer in a bit

Comment: How do you control this via CLI? Must I have a GUI?

Comment: @emrecnl sorry for the late reply. The Mega Sync Client, at the time of writing, is a GUI only application.

Comment: @emrecnl there is a package in the universe repository called [megatools](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/megatools) which claims to be a CLI for mega. (I haven't used it yet, so I can't say much more than that.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GUI (Gdebi package installer) to install it after downloading the software from MegaSync website.