# Unable to add program to startup list

Tags: virtualbox, startup, cron

I want to add the MEGA sync program to my Ubuntu 12.04 startup list. The download package for MEGA includes an executable which starts the program when opened. Either by finding it with the gui or simply typing into the terminal:

```
~/Downloads/megasync/usr/bin/megasync
```

will start the program. However, when I add this command into the startup applications program in Ubuntu it does not work. When the computer reboots and I open the startup applications program, the item is just blank fields now like so:

[image]

(This is after clicking Edit in the sidebar.)

I've even tried adding the command as a cronjob like so:

@reboot ~/Downloads/megasync/usr/bin/megasync

and once again nothing happens. Also, checking the "Start on startup" box in the MEGAsync settings window does nothing. When the computer reboots, the box is unchecked again.

I should say that I'm using a virtual machine. But I don't think that would make a difference here.

Any thoughts?

EDIT - I downloaded the megasync client from https://mega.co.nz/#sync

```
which megasync
```

This produces no output. 
`whereis -b megasync` produces

```
megasync:
```

`ls -al ~/scripts/usr/bin/megasync` produces

```
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 pf pathfinder 4881172 May  3 19:53 /home/pf/scripts/usr/bin/megasync
```

Note I did copy megasync to a new directory.

Comment: Please look here: http://askubuntu.com/a/624890/72216 there are two possible bottlenecks: use absolute paths (you *must* do that anyway, like @eldergeek mentioned), or timing issues: some commands break if they run before the desktop is fully loaded, see the link.

Comment: In your case, I would try adding: `/bin/bash -c "sleep 20&&/absolute/path/to/megasync"` to startup applications.

Comment: Did you by any chance install it following these instructions? http://askubuntu.com/questions/545299/how-do-i-install-the-mega-sync-client

Comment: @JacobVlijm This did not work.

Comment: @ElderGeek Nope. I just downlaoded the client and ran the executable.

Comment: @codedude Then try increasing the `sleep 20` (start with 90, if it works, decreas it step by step). Probably as a result of being a VM, the loading time needs to be increased. *If* the command works normally, I am pretty sure it should work.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the output of the following `which megasync`, `whereis -b megasync` and `ls -la  ~/Downloads/megasync/usr/bin/` also tell us where you downloaded the client from. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Note: If you didn't follow http://askubuntu.com/questions/545299/how-do-i-install-the-mega-sync-client where the author provides instruction you may find that the appropriate PPA isn't added to your software sources and that you don't get required updates.

Comment: @ElderGeek I realize I won't get the updates. I downloaded it from here: https://mega.co.nz/#sync I'm updating my post with those commands.

Comment: Downloading from the link provided results in a deb package. Did you install it through the software center?

Answer (score 2):

The path you provided is virtual in that the `~` stands for /home/$USERNAME$ where $USERNAME$ is your username. Try again with a full path like /home/pf/scripts/usr/bin/megasync. Replace `pf` with your actual username. Clearly you have execute permissions for megasync so that's not the issue. `which megasync` coming up blank indicates to me that that bash can't find the executable (it's not on your path). For more on the differences between which and whereis see: https://superuser.com/questions/40301/which-whereis-differences. If it's a timing play as Jacob Vlijm indicates in the comments you could call it with a homemade script that includes the necessary sleep time. **You should simply re-install it as it appears it wasn't installed correctly.** When I install via software center I get megasync placed on my path. I doubt moving the executable around has helped you. The following should produce the following result if megasync is installed correctly.

```
 which megasync
/usr/bin/megasync
```

after proper installation `ls- al /usr/bin/megasync` should produce

`-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4807432 May  3 20:56 /usr/bin/megasync` clearly what you have is the wrong size and carries the wrong ownership. The copy you have may have been an extremely short lived interim release or may have been corrupted in some fashion. If anything is unclear, please advise and I'll attempt to clarify.

Comment: This did not work.