# Software manager won't install deb file

Tags: package-management, dpkg, software-center, deb

Since I switched to Ubuntu, I have been having tons of problems. This is only one of them.

The software manager seems to be unable to install deb files; For example, I have tried to install MegaSync from its .deb file, but when I click install, it looks like if it began loading and then the install button appears again as if it wasn't touched. Here's a GIF of what I'm talking about:

[image: GIF]

Doesn't even ask for my password, and of course, the software doesn't install. It's strange, because I could install Opera using a .deb file before.

Things I have tried;

- To run *sudo apt update* in the terminal

  [image]
- Restart device

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** After another restart, I could install some apps; However, I am still unable to open/launch MEGASync.

**EDIT 2:** This is not a duplicate; Megasync is not the only not working deb, I am having some others that are not working, such as Gdebi and WPS Office.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install the Mega Sync Client](https://askubuntu.com/questions/545299/how-do-i-install-the-mega-sync-client)

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I don't think this is a duplicate of "How do I install the Mega Sync Client", since some other programs such as WPS Office and gdebi aren't working neither

Comment: Possibly. But then you have messed up the package system somehow, and need help to fix that. To start with, can you please open a terminal window, run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` and let us know the complete output by editing your question.

Comment: Alright, this is what I get: https://i.imgur.com/hx6MYfx.png

Comment: It's better to copy the output and paste it into the question. Anyway, the error message in the end might be a result of the failed installation attempt. So can you please run `sudo apt purge megasync` and then run `sudo apt upgrade` again to see if the error is gone.

Comment: Hey there, I actually got rid of the error by doing "sudo dpkg --configure  -a" because that's what it said in the terminal. Now when I do "sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade" the last terminal message says  "0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.". Is it fixed? Thanks

Comment: Yes, then it's probably fixed. Please take a look at karel's answer then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The error message in your comment says that dpkg was interrupted. First you must run the command `sudo dpkg --configure -a` in the terminal to correct this problem.
2. You mistakenly downloaded megasync-xUbuntu_16.10_amd64.deb, however you are using Ubuntu 16.04, not 16.10, so download megasync-xUbuntu_16.04_amd64.deb for Ubuntu 16.04 instead.
3. Then try to install the MegaSync .deb file again by changing to the directory that contains the Megasync .deb file that you downloaded (*megasync-xUbuntu_16.04_amd64.deb*)  with `cd` and running this command:

   ```
   sudo apt install ./megasync-xUbuntu_16.04_amd64.deb
   ```

   The advantage of this command over `sudo dpkg -i megasync-xUbuntu_16.04_amd64.deb` is that it automatically installs the package's dependencies along with the package.

Comment: Yes, those steps fixed everything. Thank you a lot to  everyone! I am very happy with the support you provided.

Answer (score -1):

I experienced a similar issue and i was able to figure out the next step by entering a terminal and doing the installation manually with dpkg:

```
cd /home/user/dir/with/package/
sudo dpkg -i package.deb
```

In most cases i would recommend  to use the package provided from the repositories or use an PPA to avoid this kind of conflice and any further conflicts it may cause.

Comment: Well, it seems like it did install the software, however, I am unable to open it... I already allowed executing the file as program, but still doesn't launch

Comment: How do you execute it and what is the result? Is there an error message in the terminal? Did you try "dpkg --listfiles package.deb" to see where it did install its files?

Comment: When running the first command you sent,  the following appeared in the terminal: https://i.imgur.com/y8bAWoN.png And when I ran the last command, I got the following: https://i.imgur.com/VHihaKD.png  And also, I am now having the same issue with other apps like WPS Office

Comment: @Jesús: It looks like you downloaded the wrong .deb file. I understand that you are on Ubuntu 16.04, and hence it's the .deb for 16.04 - for your architecture (32 or 64 bit) - you should download and install.

Comment: From https://i.imgur.com/y8bAWoN.png it appears like these packages are blocking the installation: libc-ares2, libcrypto++6, libqt5core5a, libqt5svg5

You can either install them manually  with apt, but this may also cause further dependeny issues. I'd give it a try though. Usually this happens, when an outdated version of a library should be installed.

Often there is a PPA in place to solve that issue for everybody, but i did not find one for mega: however there is this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/545299/how-do-i-install-the-mega-sync-client

Comment: Actually @GunnarHjalmarsson was right, I accidentally downloaded the wrong file. I'm sorry. Thank you all because of your useful help. This question can be closed now (I would close it myself, but I don't know how to do it)

Comment: Most of the time, questions stay here to help out future visitors. You could add the solution to the original question and upvote if the answer did help you...